# Pasar variables con hidden entre varios codigos

Tags: php, html

Tengo que hacer una pagina en php que permita rellenar una encuesta de trabajo, guardarlo en un archivo y eliminarlo, sin embargo, esta ultima parte me esta dando problemas. Me explico.

El procedimiento que estoy usando para eliminar la encuesta consta de tres partes.
Primero te pregunta por el numero de empleado (NE), pues previamente he hecho que cree que un archivo que guarde las respuestas de la encuesta con el nombre de NE introducido.

```
 <h1>Solicitud de eliminación</h1>
        <h2>Para eliminar la encuesta, por favor, escriba su NE</h2>

            <form method="POST" action="eliminarencuesta.php">

                <p><label><input type="text" name="nombrearchivoNE" placeholder="Escriba su NE"></label></p>

                <p><label><input type="submit" name="submit"></label></p>
```

Luego se cerciora de que realmente quieras eliminar el formulario.

```
 $nombrearchivo=$_POST["nombrearchivoNE"];


            if (file_exists($nombrearchivo)) {

                 echo "<h2>¿Está seguro de que desea eliminar la encuesta? </h2>";



                 echo "<form method=POST action=etapafinaleliminar.php>";

                        

                        echo "<p><label><input type=submit name=opciones value=Si></label></p>";

                         echo "<p><label><input type=submit name=opciones value=No></label</p>";

                    
                        echo "</form>";
```

Y finalmente lo elimina ( o lo intenta, porque esta es la parte que me da problemas)

```
 $nombrearchivo=$_POST["nombrearchivoNE"];
        $opciones=$_POST["opciones"];

            if ($opciones=="Si") {
            
                echo "<h1>Eliminación confirmada</h1>";

                    unlink ($nombrearchivo);

                        echo "Encuesta borrada, gracias por su colaboración.";
            }
```

Lo que me da problemas es que en este ultimo codigo no reconoce el valor 'nombrearchivoNE' y da error.

Un profesor me ha dicho que tengo que guardar el valor de 'nombrearchivoNE' en un input hidden, pero no consigo que funcione. También he probado algunos otras cosas que he visto por aquí como usar GET en vez de POST o usar href, pero no he logrado que funcione.

Resumiendo, a ver si me podeis decir como pasar el valor 'nombrearchivoNE' con hidden o de alguna otra manera.

Gracias.

Comment: No tomes directamente el nombre del archivo desde `$_POST`, es un riesgo muy serio, imagina que el usuario modifica el formulario y pone `config.php` o algún otro archivo de tu proyecto, efectivamente, se va a eliminar. Por favor edita la pregunta para explicar cómo guardas la encuesta y si el nombre del archivo es solo el número de empleado o agregas una extensión (altamente recomendable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que los valores `POST` son volátiles, quiere decir que existen cuando cargas una página a través de un `submit`. Pero si de ahí recargas otra página, estos se eliminan de la memoria a menos que lo agregues al formulario. Una forma de pasar los datos a la otra página, es como mencionas, con [input hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden)

El primer archivo está correcto, solo falta el cierre del `form`

```
<h1>Solicitud de eliminación</h1>
<h2>Para eliminar la encuesta, por favor, escriba su NE</h2>
<form method="POST" action="eliminarencuesta.php">
    <p><label><input type="text" name="nombrearchivoNE" placeholder="Escriba su NE"></label></p>
    <p><label><input type="submit" name="submit"></label></p>
</form>
```

El segundo archivo, `eliminarencuesta.php` tiene varios problemas. Los `input "type"` deben ir con comillas, por lo que si se van a imprimir con `echo`, generalmente se utilizan comillas simples afuera, para usar las dobles dentro y tratar de mantener el estándar (lo mismo para `form action=""`). 
En este archivo es donde capturas la variable `$_POST['nombrearchivoNE']`. Pero una vez le des al botón `submit` nuevamente, este valor se perderá. Para evitarlo se agrega un campo `hidden` con ese dato para que sea pasado al nuevo archivo:

*eliminarencuesta.php*

```
<?php
$nombrearchivo=$_POST["nombrearchivoNE"];
if (file_exists($nombrearchivo)) {
    echo "<h2>¿Está seguro de que desea eliminar la encuesta? </h2>";
    echo '<form method=POST action="etapafinaleliminar.php">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="nombrearchivoNE" value="'.$nombrearchivo.'">';
        echo '<p><label><input type="submit" name=opciones value=Si></label></p>';
        echo '<p><label><input type="submit" name=opciones value=No></label></p>';
    echo '</form>';
}
```

Finalmente el ultimo archivo queda casi sin cambios:

*etapafinaleliminar.php*

```
<?php
$nombrearchivo=$_POST["nombrearchivoNE"];
$opciones=$_POST["opciones"];
if ($opciones=="Si") {
    echo "<h1>Eliminación confirmada</h1>";
    unlink ($nombrearchivo);
    echo "Encuesta borrada, gracias por su colaboración.";
}
```